# Google App Engine/Python - Change logging formatting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, python-logging

How can one change the formatting of output from the `logging` module in Google App Engine?

I've tried, e.g.:

```
  log_format = "* %(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s"
  date_format = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"

  console = logging.StreamHandler()
  fr = logging.Formatter(log_format)
  console.setFormatter(fr)

  logger = logging.getLogger()
  logger.addFilter(SuperfluousFilter())
  logger.addHandler(console)

  logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

  logging.error("Reconfiguring logging")
```

However this results in duplicate logging output: One with the logging handler from [`google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py`](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py#2368) (or somewhere in the Google code), and one from my new `StreamHandler` above. The above code outputs:

```
ERROR    2010-06-23 20:46:18,871 initialize.py:38] Reconfiguring logging
2010-06-23 20:46:18,871 ERROR    Reconfiguring logging
```

Where the top line is clearly from `dev_appserver.py`, the bottom line from my code.

So I guess the corollary question is: How can change the formatting of Google App Engine, yet avoid the duplicate output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way you can change the logging format without duplicating output:

```
# directly access the default handler and set its format directly
logging.getLogger().handlers[0].setFormatter(fr)
```

This is a bit of a hack because you have to directly access the `handlers` list stored in the root logger.  The problem is GAE automatically uses `logging` before your code is ever run - this creates a default handler.  Unfortunately, I don't see how you can get a reference to this handler without directly accessing the `handlers` list as above.

Comment: That's very helpful. Another option I've considered running `setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` on the root logger, and creating a new logger to stderr.