# On the google app engine, how do I change the default logging level of the dev_appserver.py?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

Dev_appserver.py (the local development server for Python google app engine) spews tons of useless INFO messages. I would like to up this to WARN or ERROR. How can I do that?

I've tried the following,  but it has no effect...

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Funny, in their GAE documentation - http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html#Serving - they use this construct:  `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`.  Maybe it worked once upon a time, but is now broken?

Comment: 3 years later... it looks like it's still broken...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, from the command line, you can only lower the logging level to DEBUG by the '-d' command line option.

---

If you're not afraid of editing the scripts, look for

```
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
  ...
  ARG_LOG_LEVEL: logging.INFO,
```

in C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py

Comment: not sure -d option still works... does it? I got this error message "dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -d"

Comment: Instead of `-d` set the specific log level using `--log_level`. E.g. `dev_appserver.py --log_level debug .`.

Answer (score 2):

```
logging.getLogger().handlers[0].setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

from [Google App Engine/Python - Change logging formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105521/google-app-engine-python-change-logging-formatting),

> This is a bit of a hack because you have to directly access the
>   handlers list stored in the root logger. The problem is GAE
>   automatically uses logging before your code is ever run - this creates
>   a default handler

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have

```
      <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
```

in your appengine-web.xml file, then go on to change `.level = WARNING` in your logging.properties file.

That's it!

Comment: Thanks Ashwin. Sorry, I didn't realize the Java version had a dev_appserver too. I actually use Python, so my question is about python logging. I'll clarify :)