# How to change the logging level of dev_appserver

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, appserver

Do you know how to change the logging level of Google App Engine `dev_appserver`?
I would like to set it to ERROR removing messages like:

```
INFO     2011-10-18 17:43:00,806 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:637] 
         Running application foo on port 8106: http://localhost:8106
INFO     2011-10-18 17:47:12,927 dev_appserver.py:4247] 
         "GET /images/sprite.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27020180/276125

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two slightly different arguments which let you control the log level, `log_level` and `dev_appserver_log_level`.

---

**log_level** {debug,info,warning,critical,error}
`dev_appserver.py --log_level=debug`

The log level below which logging messages *generated by application code* will not be displayed on the console (default: info)

---

**dev_appserver_log_level** {debug,info,warning,critical,error}
`dev_appserver.py --dev_appserver_log_level=debug`

The log level below which logging messages *generated by the development server* will not be displayed on the console (default: info)

Comment: Answer is missing an equal sign but is on the right track.  Try --log_level=debug. For more info:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver

Comment: I struggled a bit, it looks in the bottom of `--help` there is another argument you can pass named `--dev_appserver_log_level` which controls the output successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, there isn't a way to modify the log level from the command line. Your solution is fine (at least until the next update, as you said).

You could pipe it through a GREP if you want, eg.:

```
~/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py . 2>&1 |egrep "^(WARNING|ERROR|CRITICAL)"
```

Not ideal but functional.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer does not work for me, but the comments to the accepted answer do give a fix.  This is a community wiki answer to help avoid confusion.

`dev_appserver.py --dev_appserver_log_level=debug` sets the log output to debug level.

Answer (score 0):

I have directly modified the source of `dev_appserver_main.py` in:

```
ARG_LOG_LEVEL: logging.ERROR
```

On the next update I will lose this change but it is not a problem; I really wanted this because log console tend to freeze on huge imports from program (I'm on OSX).

Answer (score 0):

In the Google App Engine Launcher select Edit->Application Settings, and add --debug into Extra Command Line Flags.