# How to Run Wordpress Blog on Google App Engine Locally

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

Following the [Wordpress on GAE tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard), I have managed to successfully deploy my blog to App Engine.

However, I would like to be able to run my blog locally as I continue its development, so that I can inspect error logs, etc. Using the [GAE dev server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server#PHP_Running_the_development_web_server), I try to run it like so:

```
dev_appserver.py --log_level=debug app.yaml --php_executable_path=/usr/local/bin/php
```

But I run into this problem:

```
The url "/" does not match any handlers.
```

I have not changed my `app.yaml` nor any other file (the ones auto-created by the wp-gae.php step in the tutorial). It looks like this:

```
# App Engine runtime configuration
runtime: php72

# Defaults to "serve index.php" and "serve public/index.php". Can be used to
# serve a custom PHP front controller (e.g. "serve backend/index.php") or to
# run a long-running PHP script as a worker process (e.g. "php worker.php").
entrypoint: serve gae-app.php

service: test-wp

# Defines static handlers to serve WordPress assets
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))
  static_files: \1
  upload: .*\.(htm|html|css|js)$

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))
  static_files: wp-content/\1
  upload: wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))
  static_files: \1
  upload: .*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$

- url: /wp-includes/images/media/(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))
  static_files: wp-includes/images/media/\1
  upload: wp-includes/images/media/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
```

Any ideas on how I can:

1. fix the URL error above?
2. enable debug logs to show up on my console? I just get `INFO     2019-05-29 10:58:02,913 module.py:861] test-wp: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -` I've tried both the flags `--log_level=debug` and `--dev_appserver_log_level=debug` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17350827/1145905) and `echo` nor `syslog(LOG_DEBUG,'test')` print statements are not working as expected. On my wp-config.php, I have: `define('WP_DEBUG', !$onGae);`

Answer (score 0):

logs viewer from stackdriver logging has logs https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?
the logs include your localhost logs

Answer (score 0):

I took couldn't figure out how to get this to work. Unrelated to the logging response, I came across this post: https://introvertedengineer.com/2017/02/20/appengine-and-wordpress-guide/

Which spelled out how the using GAE might not be the best approach:

> The big elephant in the room when dealing with App Engine is that your
>   application does not have access to a file system. What does this
>   mean? Well, you can’t autoupdate WordPress, you can’t install plugins,
>   you can’t install themes, etc. If you’re used to being able to do
>   these things via the WordPress admin, you’re going to be disappointed.
>   Like all things, however, there is a workaround!
>
> I first attempted to just run the local Google App Engine SDK and
>   start up my App Engine application that way. Turns out, however, that
>   locally you still don’t have file system access—yeah, even on
>   localhost! So you’ll need to run a local FTP server and then have
>   WordPress make changes via FTP instead of directly on the filesystem.
>   When you’re done with your local changes, you can use Google’s SDK to
>   deploy a new version of your app up to your production instance.

The write up is a little outdated since GAE now supports PHP 7, but the file system aspect still seems to be true (would love to be proven wrong).

I ultimately used MAMP to run wordpress locally (https://www.mamp.info/en/), which was an extra workaround, but got through it.