# How to run Google App Engine WordPress blog locally

Tags: google-app-engine

Following the Wordpress on GAE tutorial, I have managed to successfully deploy my blog to App Engine. 
However, I would like to be able to run my blog locally as I continue its development, so that I can inspect error logs, etc. Using the GAE dev server, I try to run it like so:

```
dev_appserver.py --log_level=debug app.yaml --php_executable_path=/usr/local/bin/php
```

But I run into this problem:

> The url "/" does not match any handlers.

I have not changed my app.yaml nor any other file (the ones auto-created by the wp-gae.php step in the tutorial). It looks like this:

[How to Run Wordpress Blog on Google App Engine Locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56359130/1145905)

```
dev_appserver.py --log_level=debug app.yaml --php_executable_path=/usr/local/bin/php
```

the blog should run on my local setup

Comment: If your app.yaml file is the same as the one that's linked then it could be that there is no handler that matches `"/"`. I think `url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))` doesn't match `"/"` so you try adding a new handler to your app.yaml

Answer (score 0):

according to this [forum link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/BzETbaSebbM) you need to specify the php-cgi executable.

```sh
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=$(which python2) && dev_appserver.py --support_datastore_emulator=False --log_level=debug --php_executable_path=$(which php-cgi) app.yaml
```

i also had to add a handler to app.yaml to get the site to work, make sure its the last handler (lowest priority)

```
- url: .*
  script: gae-app.php
```